# Density of integers represented by a binary quadratic form is zero

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $q(x_1,x_2):=ax_1^2+bx_1x_2+cx_2^2$ be a positive-definite quadratic form with $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Let $r_q(n)$ be the number of natural numbers $k\leq n$ that are represented by $q$, i.e., such that $q(x_1,x_2)=k$ for some $x_1,x_2\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Is it necessarily true that the probability of a random number being representable by $q$ is zero, in the sense that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{r_q(n)}{n}=0$?

In the nice example $q(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$, we have that $r_q(n)$ is proportional to $\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ (according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) article), so $\frac{r_q(n)}{n}$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}$, which tends to zero.

Less pleasant examples like $q(x_1,x_2)=3x_1+7x_2^2-x_1x_2$ seem to be much more restrictive on possible representations, so it looks like the conjecture should be true.

Given that quadratic forms are intensely studied since Gauss (at least), I imagine this must be something well-known.

Comment: i think you can get started with this? https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/form.html#:~:text=A%20binary%20quadratic%20form%20is%20written%20%5B%20a%2C,gcd%20%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%201%20are%20primitive%20representations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a\, q(x,y) = 4 a^2 (2x-(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})y)(2x-(-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac})y) $$

- If $b^2-4ac$ is not a square then $q(x,y)$ will be a norm in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{b^2-4ac})$ where half of primes are non-split so the integer norms have density $0$ (and asymptotic $r \frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}$).
- If $b^2-4ac$ is a square then $a q(x,y)$ is equivalent

  - either to $x^2-y^2$ if $b^2-4ac\ne 0$ (which has density $1/2$ but is not positive-definite)
  - or $(x+y)^2$ if $b^2-4ac=0$  which has density $0$ (and asymptotic $\sqrt{n}$) and is only semi positive-definite.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay in accepting your answer. About the claims that "half of the primes are non-split" and "density asymptotic to $r\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}$", what references would you recommend?

Comment: I'm having a real hard time finding a reference for the $r\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ asymptotic behavior. I certainly don't know how to prove it

Comment: @rmdmc89 Similar proof as for the PNT: tauberian theorem with $\prod_{(\frac{b^2-4ac}{p})=1}\frac1{1-p^{-s}} \prod_{(\frac{b^2-4ac}{p})=-1} \frac1{1-p^{-2s}} $ whose square is known to have a simple pole at $s=1$ and analytic elsewhere on $\Re(s)\ge 1$ by the PNT for $L(s,(\frac{b^2-4ac}{p}))$

Comment: I think I understand you a little better now. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$, where $\Delta:=b^2-4ac$. A prime $p\in\Bbb{Z}$ is inert in $\mathcal{O}_K$ iff $(\frac{\Delta}{p})=-1$ (in which case $N(p\mathcal{O}_K)=p^2$), splits iff $(\frac{\Delta}{p})=1$ (here $N(p\mathcal{O}_K)=p$) and is ramified iff $p|\Delta$ (again $N(p\mathcal{O}_K)=p$). Now we decompose the factors of  $\zeta_K(s)=\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal{O}_K}(1-\frac{1}{N(\mathfrak{p})^s})$ as $(\prod\frac{1}{1-p^s})^2$ for the primes $p$ that split and $\prod\frac{1}{1-p^{2s}}$ for the primes that are inert or ramify.

Comment: I still don't see how do we get to zero density with all this